# SVG opacity doesn't work in Safari

Tags: svg, safari

I have a background image with a opacity. It works fine in firefox and Chrome but it's opacity doesn't work in Safari. Is there anyway to fix this or is it not supported in Safari?

This is my SVG

```
<svg version="1.1"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"    xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/"
 x="0px" y="0px" width="640.2px" height="1136px" viewBox="0 0 640.2 1136" style="enable-background:new 0 0 640.2 1136;"
 xml:space="preserve">

<style type="text/css">
.st0{fill:#5AAAFA;}
.st1{opacity:4.000000e-02;}
</style>
<defs>
</defs>
<polygon id="XMLID_18_" class="st0" points="640.2,1136 0.2,1136 0.2,0 640.2,0 640.2,367.1 "/>
<path id="XMLID_17_" class="st1" d="M0,810.6c0.1,108.5,0.2,216.9,0.2,325.4h640c-  0.4-320.4-0.7-640.8-1.1-961.2
C426.1,386.7,213.1,598.7,0,810.6z"/>
</svg>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently some browsers have trouble with numbers written using scientific notation (like `4.000000e-02` instead of `0.04`). This is a bug, since [scientific number representations are permitted by the CSS standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#numbers).

But there's an easy workaround; just change this:

```
opacity:4.000000e-02;
```

to this:

```
opacity:0.04;
```

and it should work.